# What is the difference between a PT3 and a PT4 power lead?

Tags: power-supply, dc, wiring

I want to know the difference between a PT4 and a PT3 power lead.
 Can I use them interchangeably?

http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/CCTV-Accessory-PT4-p/pt-4.htm

http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Power-Cable-Lead-p/pt-3.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two leads are NOT interchangeable.
 One is the "complement" of the other.
 The two will connect together as "plug & socket"

PT3 is referred to as a female connector.
 PT4 is referred to as a male connector.

The PT3 has a hollow centre and it connects to a PT4 which has a 2.1mm "spike" in the centre.

In the photos below note how the PT3 and PT4 can be fitted together.

This photo shows a PT3 connector and cable

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuSjt.jpg]

This photo shows a PT4 connector and cable.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mhEc.jpg]

---

[This web page](http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/CCTV-Accessory-PT4-p/pt-4.htm)  says:

- PT-4 power leads are typically used to connect the 18 guage pair of power cable to RG-59 siamese cable to a security cameras DC power plug input.

  PT-4 power leads can also be used with pro box style security cameras that do not typically have a DC power plug attached to them.  Box security cameras typically have screw terminals for a positive and negative wire connection.  If you are using plug and play cables, you can attach a PT-4 to the cameras power terminals for a clean connection to your plug and play cables.

  PT-4s provide 1 foot of cable and **a male connector** for CCTV Camera power.
  **The diameter of the connector is 2.1mm** which is the standard size used for plug and play cables.

[This web page says](http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Power-Cable-Lead-p/pt-3.htm)  says similarly, except

- ... PT-3s provide 6 inches of cable **and a female connector** for CCTV Camera power.
  **The diameter of the connector is 2.1mm** which is the standard size used for plug and play cables.